# I need to pull all the digits after the word CaseID- that are in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse an email.subject line and look for the CaseID-

The CaseID- is sometimes at the beginning at sometimes at the end so I need to pull it out.  I do not know the length of the CaseID- but I do know it is all digits run together.

Here are sample subject lines:

```
[EXTERNAL] SupportCentral Case Ownership, CASEID-372146
[EXTERNAL] CaseID-372128, SupportCentral Case Transferred, Testing Dispatch
```

How do I do this?

Thank you,
Stacy

Comment: Are you familiar with [regular expressions?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Your question could be improved with some specific examples.  Is it `CaseID: xxxxxx` or just some number in the subject to be found, or is there some other pattern that exists in the subjects.  Examples are very important if you want help.

Comment: [Here is a very simple regex example that could potentially solve your problem to get you started](https://regex101.com/r/igmX0b/1).

Comment: Here are sample subject lines: [EXTERNAL] SupportCentral Case Ownership, CASEID-372146 or [EXTERNAL] CaseID-372128, SupportCentral Case Transferred, Testing Dispatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is a job for a regular expression, as @gview mentioned.

```
const subj = 'Subject: please refer to CaseID-123456 in future correspondence'
const caseNumber = subj.replace(/^.*CaseID-(\d+).*$/,'$1')
console.log(caseNumber)
```

You can read about regular expressions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

The regular expression in this case is `/^.*CaseID-(\d+).*$/`.

- `/` means the start of the regex
- `^` means match the start of the string you give it.
- `.` means match any character
- `.*` means match zero or more of any character
- `CaseID-` means match that text
- `(` means begin a so-called *capture group*
- `\d` means match any numeric digit [0-9]
- `\d+` means match one or more numeric digits
- `)` ends the capture group
- `.*` again means match zero or more of any character
- `$` means match the end of the string.
- `/` ends the regex

And, in the second parameter we have `'$1'` which means replace the string with the first capture group.

And shazam, you have your case id number.  `123456` in my example.

In the old days we used to say that the best way to write regular expressions was to whistle into a modem.  Now, writing them involves cats on keyboards.

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT***

With the given clarity of the new OP edit, the other answer is more fitting. However, I did not have that information when I made my answer. I'd defer to that one then.

```js
const id = "CaseID-23453245643245642345632456543245-CaseID"
const regex = /^.*CaseID-(\d+).*$/;
const decode = id.replace(regex,'$1')

console.log(decode);
```

Comment: It's not even clear that the word 'CaseID' is even part of the subject.

Comment: Her comment amendment said so.

Comment: I appreciate it. It's now been edited *again* to give more clarity, so my answer doesn't 1:1 translate anymore. Oh well. hahaha

Comment: It happens.  Just update your answer if you feel a tweaked regex would be more appropriate.